# How to properly apply a sklearn pipeline to new data, two different setups tested

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, train-test-split, pycaret

I used the package pycaret to create a pipeline for my dataset. Now I want to use this pipeline and apply it to my own train and test splits that I create from the data. OneHotEncoding is one of the steps in my pipeline. Because of this, the transformed X_train has a different number of columns as my X_test data, due to the number of unique values for some columns being different.

To circumvent this issue, I had the idea to first fit the transform related steps of my pipeline to all my data and only fit the predictor (GradientBoostingClassifier) to the training data. To accomplish this, I have the two setups described below. The steps

Setup 1:
Here we first fit and transform all our data. From this transformed data we can now pull our train and test data and fit the predictor
[image]

setup 2: Here we first only fit the pipeline on all data. The train and test splits are taken directly from the original data and then get transformed using the fitted pipeline.
[image]

Both of these setups seem to work (as in, they give no error). However, in my case they both  seem to produce different output (with the same seed). This is a major cause of concern since I assumed the result would be exactly the same. Below is the output.

```
accuracy  : 0.732
Time taken: 171

accuracy  : 0.805
Time taken: 184
```

I have 2 questions about this problem.

1. Are these setups appropriate to deal with such a problem, or are there any other best practices that I am missing?
2. What could be the reason that the accuracy scores are different? They should be identical, right?

code setup 1:

```html
predictor = load_predictor(1)
predictor_pipeline = predictor[:-1]
predictor_model = predicto1[-1]

start = perf_counter()

print('Fitting pipeline')
X, y = dataset[config.INPUT_FEATURES + [target]], dataset[target]
X_transformed = predictor_pipeline.fit_transform(X, y)

train_set, test_set = create_sets()

train_df = tools.keep_subset(dataset,'index',train_set)
test_df = tools.keep_subset(dataset,'index',test_set)

train_indices = train_df.index
test_indices = test_df.index

# print('Adding weights')
train_df['sample_weights'] = self.add_sample_weights(train_df)
test_df['sample_weights'] = self.add_sample_weights(test_df)

X_train, y_train, weights_train = X_transformed.iloc[train_indices], train_df[target], train_df['sample_weights']
X_test, y_test, weights_test = X_transformed.iloc[test_indices], test_df[target], test_df['sample_weights']

print('Fitting predictor')
predictor_model.fit(X_train,y_train,sample_weight=weights_train)
preds = predictor_model.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy := accuracy_score(y_test, preds, sample_weight=weights_test))
print(f'Time taken: {perf_counter() - start}')
```

code setup 2:

```html
target = 'won'

predictor = self.load_predictor(1)
predictor_pipeline = predictor[:-1]
predictor_model = predictor[-1]

start = perf_counter()

print('Fitting processor ..')
X, y = dataset[config.INPUT_FEATURES + [target]], dataset[target]
predictor_pipeline.fit(X, y)

train_set, test_set = create_sets()

train_df = tools.keep_subset(self.dataset,'index',train_set)
test_df = tools.keep_subset(self.dataset,'index',test_set)

print('Adding weights')
train_df['sample_weights'] = self.add_sample_weights(train_df)
test_df['sample_weights'] = self.add_sample_weights(test_df)

predictor_1 = self.load_predictor(1)
X_train, y_train, weights_train = train_df[config.INPUT_FEATURES + [target]], train_df[target], train_df['sample_weights']
X_test, y_test, weights_test = test_df[config.INPUT_FEATURES + [target]], test_df[target], test_df['sample_weights']

print('Processing training and test data ..')
X_train = predictor_pipeline.transform(X_train)
X_test = predictor_pipeline.transform(X_test)

print('Fitting model ...')
predictor_model.fit(X_train,y_train,sample_weight=weights_train)
preds = predictor_model.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_test, preds, sample_weight=weights_test))
print(f'Time taken: {perf_counter() - start}')
```

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would really help out here.  The two methods should have the same result; the culprit could be your `create_sets` or `tools.keep_subset` not getting the same split in the two runs, or one of your pipeline steps not working correctly, or a random element in the transformers or model, or something else.  (Also, you generally shouldn't fit transformers to the combined train/test set, but that's a subject for stats.SE or datascience.SE.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My suspect would be that it is a random element in one of the transformers. I'll dive deeper into the exact steps that it is taking.

Comment: Are you sure you have set `random_state=0` within your model that has been chained into your pipeline `Pipeline(steps=[('SGD', SGDRegressor(random_state=0))])` for your models and somewhere you split data into train & test again `train_test_split(X, y, ...  random_state=0)` to get stable/reproducible results ? check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74042553/10452700) and its comment that might help