# non-reproducible results in repeated nested CV

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

My results lack reproducibility, and I don't understand why.

**Context:**

Using sklearn, I am training a pipeline

`[transform, dimredux, model]`

where transform is non-stochastic.

I am using an inner CV for model selection and a repeated outer CV for performance estimation.

I use GridSearchCV to search over a few dimension reduction / feature selection methods, a few models, and a few hyper-parameter values for those models. This is the inner CV of the nested CV.

This GridSearchCV is nested within an outer CV and is repeated several times for estimating the generalization/performance.

The results need to be reproducible, therefore I provide a value for each random_state argument I can find. Yet, my results seem to vary.

**Overview of `random_state` arguments:**

- As I use the full data set in a repeated nested CV context, **no train test split** is done. So no randomness there.
- **dim redux:** PCA, `SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif())`, and `RFE(estimator=SVC())` all have a `random_state` argument, which is seeded with `np.random.seed(42)`, I also have `VarianceThreshold` which does not have such argument
- **models:** LogisticRegression, RandomForestClassifier, SVC, GradientBoostingClassifier all have a `random_state argument`, which is seeded with np.random.seed(42)
- **(inner) GridSearchCV:** For the cv argument, I provide a `StratifiedKFold` instance with `np.random.seed(42)` as value for the random_state argument
- **repeated outer CV:** a RepeatedStratifiedKFold instance is used, again with the same value for the random_state argument. Upon checking, the indices are different across splits and repeats and are reproducible.

I first used large numbers as value for the `random_state`, then integers, now the `np.random.seed(42)`. However with every 'setup' I am not able to reproduce my results across complete repetitions of the repeated nested CV.

**Versions:**

- Python 3.8.13
- sklearn 1.0.2
- numpy 1.21.5

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `numpy.random.seed` works with `random_state`, but using integers for `random_state` is fine and even preferred (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69756672/10495893). As for where _that_ might fail, providing a minimalized example to play with would help.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Making a minimal reproducible example was a good exercise. Turns out I must have been mixing integers with the `random.seed`. For now, I can reproduce the non-reproducibility with `random.seed`, but with integers the results are reproducible. Also, your reaction to how `random.seed` works with `random_state` made me realize I was mixing `random.seed` up with `random.RandomState`.